# php Array Initialization

Tags: php, arrays, initialization

I need to initialize an array of objects in PHP.
Presently I have the following code:

```
$comment = array();
```

And when i am adding an element to the array

```
public function addComment($c){
    array_push($this->comment,$c);
}
```

Here, `$c` is an object of class Comment.

But when I try to access an functions of that class using `$comment`, I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function
>   getCommentString() on a non-object

Can anyone tell me how to initialize an array of objects in php?

Thanks
Sharmi

Comment: You can't access the variable $this->comment by calling $comment.

Answer (score 3):

```
$this->comment = array();
```

Comment: not if the initialization is happening outside of the constructor

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a scope problem to me.

If `$comments` is a member of a class, calling `$comments` inside a function of that class will not actually use the member, but rather use an instance of `$comments` belonging to the scope of the function.

If other words, if you are trying to use a class member, do `$this->comments`, not just `$comments`.

```
class foo
{
    private $bar;

    function add_to_bar($param)
    {
        // Adds to a $bar that exists solely inside this
        // add_to_bar() function.
        $bar[] = $param;

        // Adds to a $bar variable that belongs to the
        // class, not just the add_to_bar() function.
        $this->bar[] = $param;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code might help you:

```
$comments = array();
$comments[] = new ObjectName(); // adds first object to the array
$comments[] = new ObjectName(); // adds second object to the array

// To access the objects you need to use the index of the array
// So you can do this:
echo $comments[0]->getCommentString(); // first object
echo $comments[1]->getCommentString(); // second object

// or loop through them
foreach ($comments as $comment) {
    echo $comment->getCommentString();
}
```

I think your problem is either how you are adding the objects to the array (what is $this->comment referencing to?) or you may be trying to call ->getCommentString() on the array and not on the actual objects in the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can see what's in the array by passing it to [`print_r()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php):

```
print_r($comment);
```

Presuming you have `Comment` objects in there, you should be able to reference them with `$comment[0]->getCommentString()`.